# Second part of If statement will not work

Tags: php

I have this code that should only run if a user is logged in and a column in the database is set to 1. Currently it runs even if `$Auth->subdomain` is 0 with no errors.

If i do a echo `$Auth->subdomain;` i can indeed confirm that the value is 0 and the code still executes even if it is. If i change the the if statement to this `if (!$Auth->loggedIn()):` only the code wont run if the user is not logged in.

Anyone know why it wont work with the `&& ($Auth->subdomain = 1)):` part ?

```
<?php if ($Auth->loggedIn() && ($Auth->subdomain = 1)): ?>

<?php else: ?>  

<div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `$Auth->subdomain == 1`?

Comment: wont work even if i do that. same problem

Comment: I think you also want `($Auth->loggedIn()`. I removed the !

Comment: i made the ! here while typing, it's not in the code. edited my post

Comment: You do realize that `$Auth->subdomain = 1` sets `$Auth->subdomain` to 1. It doesn't check for that value. It sets it.

Comment: ow, how do i make it check? cuase if i did echo $Auth->subdomain; in the code erlier i would get a 0 if it was 0 etc. even with == is still the same problem

Comment: Do the echo after the if and before the else.

Comment: @MichaelJS You check with `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: if i have this <?php if (!$Auth->loggedIn() && ($Auth->subdomain == "1")): ?> and do an echo after the if statement i still get 1 if the value is 1 from the start but the code still runs wich is should not when the value is 0.

Comment: loggedIn() may be returning false.

Comment: Can you show your loggedIn() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php if ($Auth->loggedIn() && ($Auth->subdomain ==1)){ ?>
<h2> You are logged in </h2>
<?php } else { ?>  

   <div>
        <h2> Not logged in </h2>
   </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: When i did this the code shows for people that is not logged in and where subdomain is set to 0. it's invisible for people who are logged in and the value of subdomain set to 1. :p i confirmed the value by a echo $Auth->subdomain; Before and after the if statement.

Comment: @Michael JS This is because of your condition. If statement body doesn't execute unless the user logged in and subdomain equal 1..

Comment: @Michael JS as you know else branch will execute if user not logged in or subdomain is not 1. that is mean even if the user is logged in and subdonain not equals 1 still executes else branch.